# VBA not going to the end of If function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that checks if rows are empty, and if they are not it prints an area on a separate sheet. I have attempted below to have the computer run through each row and run an if test. I expected it to print out two sheets (as only H2 and H3 have values) but it only prints the first row. What am I missing to have it print out two pages (or, as many pages as rows are filled)?

````
If IsEmpty(Range("H2").Value) = False Then
   Worksheets("Document").Range("A1:I45").PrintOut

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("H3").Value) = False Then
   Worksheets("Document").Range("j1:r45").PrintOut

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("H4").Value) = False Then
   Worksheets("Document").Range("s1:aa45").PrintOut

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("H5").Value) = False Then
   Worksheets("Document").Range("ab1:aj45").PrintOut

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("H6").Value) = False Then
   Worksheets("Document").Range("Ak1:as45").PrintOut

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("H7").Value) = False Then
   Worksheets("Document").Range("At1:bb45").PrintOut

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("H8").Value) = False Then
   Worksheets("Document").Range("bc1:bk45").PrintOut

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("H9").Value) = False Then
   Worksheets("Document").Range("bl1:bt45").PrintOut

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("H10").Value) = False Then
   Worksheets("Document").Range("A51:I100").PrintOut

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("H11").Value) = False Then
   Worksheets("Document").Range("j51:r100").PrintOut

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("H12").Value) = False Then
   Worksheets("Document").Range("s51:aa100").PrintOut

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("H13").Value) = False Then
   Worksheets("Document").Range("ab51:aj100").PrintOut

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("H14").Value) = False Then
   Worksheets("Document").Range("Ak51:as100").PrintOut

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("H15").Value) = False Then
   Worksheets("Document").Range("At51:bb100").PrintOut

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("H16").Value) = False Then
   Worksheets("Document").Range("bc51:bk100").PrintOut

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("H17").Value) = False Then
   Worksheets("Document").Range("bl51:bt100").PrintOut


End If
End Sub```
````

Comment: That's not how `ElseIf` works... see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements).

Answer (score 2):

As stated `IF` resolves serially and as such once it finds the first True statement it does that and skips the rest. You do not want `ElseIf` you want individual `If` statements.

```
If IsEmpty(Range("H2").Value) = False Then
   Worksheets("Document").Range("A1:I45").PrintOut
End If

If IsEmpty(Range("H3").Value) = False Then
   Worksheets("Document").Range("j1:r45").PrintOut
End If
...
```

But you can use a loop:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To 9
    If ActiveSheet.Range("H" & i) = "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1:I45").Offset(0, (i - 2) * 9).PrintOut
    End If
Next i
    For i = 10 To 17
    If ActiveSheet.Range("H" & i) = "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A51:I100").Offset(0, (i - 10) * 9).PrintOut
    End If
Next i
```

This assumes the printout area is always the same size and same spacing.